# How to mark flags as useful

Tags: discussion, flag-history, helpful-flags

I search for this question but not found a exact answer.
In user profile page, under Impact section there is a such that counter:

> `0 helpful flags`.

Where does that data come from?

How can I mark something as useful/helpful? Where  can  I do that?

Comment: What is the "something" you want to mark as helpful?  Do you have an example?  Your question is not clear because you mention flags in the title, but as a normal user, you can't even see the flags to mark them as helpful.

Comment: i updated question. In user profile page, under Impact section there is a such that counter: 0 helpful flags. i wonder that

Comment: Much clearer now.  Simple answer... you have no direct control over marking flags as helpful.  Flags are generated by users to indicate problems to moderators.  It is through the moderators (or higher reputation users reviewing posts) that flags are marked as helpful.

Comment: so, as i understand, it needs some upper level privileges?

Comment: you can get more information about flags here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 7):

You can flag posts and [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments) that are not meeting the quality standards of the site (including [spam and abusive posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)).

Those flags get recorded in your [flag-summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5295657). Your flags are either dispatched to one of the review queues for other community members to judge or to the moderator queue to be handled by a moderator

If either the community or the moderator agree with your flag the flag will be marked as helpful in your own flag-summary.
If they disagree with your flag the system will mark your flag as [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags).
If no-one could make up their mind the flag will be marked [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag).

My flag-summary looks like this:

[image]

Comment: is there any counter for declined flag?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas It's in brackets. You don't see it until you've got declined flags.